# How to extract reference file from a ".tpxz" folder using "pixz" command

Tags: bash

I want to read a compressed file form folder `test.tpxz` using command `pixz`. I am able to list the contents of the file using `pixz -l test.tpxz` but not able to read a particular reference file. Which I can do using `tar` command for example `tar tvf test.tar.xz /abc/xyz.txt`. 
Can anyone suggest me how the same thing can be done using `pixz` command? It would save my lots of time.

Comment: Deleted comment from MKB (Aug 4 '16): "Is it possible to list the hard linked file using pixz command? Because this command doesn't extract hard linked file. ... No I am not able to extract a hard linked file using `-x`"

Comment: Hey, Thanks for you valuable information. :)